# How to provide a default value to the "Ask For Text" automator function?

Tags: macos, automator

I'm working on an Automator app that receives folders. So far it looks like this:

- Set Value of Variable (var1)
- Ask For Text (default answer set to "00000 Sample Job Name")
- Set Value of Variable (var2)
- execute bash script

[image: Automator screengrab]
Right now one issue that is bothering me is that when I run the app, the dialog that appears for "Ask for text" does not offer "00000 Sample Job Name" as the default, but rather the file path that was passed to the app and assigned to var1.

Why the heck would that be?

Automator 2.5, Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: I think you need to shoe us the code

Comment: I agree with Mark - can you specify a version of OS X / Automator and show a [minimal version of your code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vDaS9.png) to provide a clear statement of what you have coded and what the results you want are? My guess is you want "foo" to be entered if the user clicks OK and it's not being set?

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried to address your questions in the edit. Basically just wondering why "foo" is not offered to the user at all in the dialog. I don't really intend for "foo" to carry through, I just think it's messy that they are shown var1 instead, for no reason I can discern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable "Ignore this action's input" for the "Ask for Text" action to retain the default value you have specified.

Comment: Thanks, that's obviously it, feel a little sheepish I didn't try that!

Comment: Many years late but, this doesn't appear to work if you have multiple inputs being captured and need to retrieve them all at the end, as they will not be in the `input` array.  Any idea how to solve this issue without losing that array?